# Codename One event listener for restarting app on coming foreground again?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to restart my Codename One app when it comes to foreground after putting it to background?

I would like to restart it as if I close and open again app, also if I have only putted it in background without closing it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you come back from background `start()` is invoked again (but not `init(Object)`) you can just show the first `Form` whenever that is invoked.

I would suggest using some special logic there as you might not want to do that if you went to the background for a couple of seconds only but that depends on your app type...